# How to select existing fabric canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to select the existing fabric canvas. I tried following code but did not work.

```
canvas=document.getElementById("imageCanvas").fabric;
```

Actually i am working with multiple canvas object of fabric. Please suggest way to select switch between multiple canvas and adding text to mutiple canvas based on selection. I also tried following code but it will not work for me because i am createing canvas object dynamically.
http://jsfiddle.net/fpHaE/19/

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the JS fiddle code you can use that code for maintaining the multiple canvases easily .

http://jsfiddle.net/upardhi/fpHaE/24/

```js
var activeCanvas, canvas1, canvas2;
var canvasList={}; /* Variable for maintaining the list of canvases*/

$(document).ready(function() {
    canvasList['canvas1'] = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');
    canvasList['canvas2'] = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2');
    changeView('canvas1');
});

function changeView(value) {
        $('.canvas-container').css('display', 'none');
        $('#'+value).parent().css('display', 'block');
    activeCanvas=canvasList[value]
  
}

function dropText() {
    var text = new fabric.Text('test');
    activeCanvas.add(text);
}
```

```css
#canvas1{border:1px solid red;}
#canvas2{border:1px solid green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.13/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeView('canvas1');">View 1</button>
<button onclick="changeView('canvas2');">View 2</button>
<button onclick="dropText();">Drop Text</button>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <canvas id="canvas1" class="canvas-area"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" class="canvas-area"></canvas>
</div>
```